# How to loop this javascript code ina cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

So here is my javascript code that I am trying to loop in a cycle. Cycle must repeat 156 times for the 156 unique id-s.

```
$("#w1").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#q1").hide();
});
$("#w2").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#q2").hide();
});
$("#w3").click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#q3").hide();
});
...etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop, and build your selector strings programatically.

Hint: `"#q" + 1` is `"#q1"`, etc. Wrap it in a `for` loop, replace `1` with a variable and you're basically done.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
for (var i=1;i<=156;i++) {  
  $("#w"+i).click(function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#q"+i).hide();
  });
```

If you instead give all ***w*** links a class then

```
$(".wclass").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var idx = this.id.substring(1);
    $("#q"+idx).hide();
});
```